# CKEditor edit config on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have config.js file, but I also want to config some buttons dynamically. Here is my code for page:

```
 CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (evt)
                  {

                    CKEDITOR.instances.MY_INSTANCE.destroy();
                    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Basic = [['Bold']];
                    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'Basic';
                    CKEDITOR.config.width=400;
                    CKEDITOR.config.height=300;
                    CKEDITOR.replace('MY_INSTANCE', CKEDITOR.config);
});
```

when I go to the page, textarea is blinking and appears/disappears all time. What's wrong? How to change ckeditor's config dynamically ?

PS. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531002/change-ckeditor-toolbar-dynamically), but it didn't help me much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This:-**

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        language: 'fr',
        uiColor: '#9AB8F3'
    });
```

[For More information click here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration)

Comment: it says "Uncaught The editor instance "MY_INSTANCE" is already attached to the provided element."

Comment: Go to the link they have described everything.

Comment: I looked up.. nothing useful

Comment: also, when I first destroy existing editor and then try to reconfifure with your code - the effect is the same - textarea blinking

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wondered about multiple editors solution, I find this to be the best one.

```
$(".ckeditor").each(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr("id"), {
        extraPlugins: 'justify,font'
    });
});
```